# Prove that $(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)(1/a_1+1/a_2+\cdots+1/a_n)\geq n^2$.

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove that $(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)(1/a_1+1/a_2+\cdots+1/a_n)\geq n^2$, for $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R^+$

This exercise with arithmetic and harmonic mean comes out very easy. The question is to test it without using that, induction or something similar. Using induction I have not come to anything, someone could give me a help, or some method to solve it other than the arithmetic and harmonic means.

What I have tried by induction is the following (skipping the step $ n = 1 $),

Let $z=a_1+\cdots+a_n,h=1/a_1+\cdots+1/a_n$, then
$$\begin{align*}(z+a_{n+1})(h+1/a_{n+1})&=zh+z/(a_{n+1})+a_{n+1}h+1\\  &\geq n^2+(a_1+\cdots+a_n)/(a_{n+1})+a_{n+1}(1/a_1+\cdots+1/a_n)+1\end{align*}$$
But then after distributing all that, I come to nothing.

Comment: What have you done so far? At what point of induction have you stopped?

Comment: I already made my attempt.

Comment: Right ... and of course it's not too difficult to show that $a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$? Then apply it to $$\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}+\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1}$$ and so on.

Comment: Sure of course, but in that case $ ab = 1$, in each sum. And it will add the $ 2 $ $ n $ times. Right?

Comment: It's a case of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @favst:   That should be developed into an answer, or is this question a duplicate ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sure, I have written up an answer with the details (I have not researched whether the question is a duplicate).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, in essence, to reprove the AM-HM inequality.  We will need AM-GM for $n=2$; if you can't use that, then reprove it as follows: \begin{gather*}
(a-b)^2\geq0 \\
a^2+b^2-2ab\geq0 \\
a^2+b^2\geq2ab \\
\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq ab
\end{gather*}

Now I turn to the claim you seek.

If $n=0$, the claim is trivial, so suppose $n\geq1$.  Let $z=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{a_j}}{n-1}$, $w=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{a_j}}}{n-1}$.  We know from induction that $zw\geq1$ and we want to show that $$((n-1)z+a_n)\left((n-1)w+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\geq n^2$$  Well, \begin{align*}
((n-1)z+a_n)\left((n-1)w+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)&=(n-1)^2zw+(n-1)za_n+(n-1)\frac{w}{a_n}+1 \\
&\geq(n-1)^2+1+(n-1)\left(a_nz+\frac{w}{a_n}\right) \\
&\geq(n-1)^2+1+(n-1)2\sqrt{(a_nz)\left(\frac{w}{a_n}\right)} \tag{1}\\
&\geq(n-1)^2+2(n-1)+1 \\
&=((n-1)+1)^2
\end{align*} where (1) comes from AM-GM.

Comment: For $\ n=1\ $ your $\ z\ $ and $\ w\ $ are undefined, so I think you need to start your induction from $\ n=1\ $ rather than $\ n=0\ $. This isn't a problem, since the inequality is still trivial for $\ n=1\ $.

Comment: Yeah, you right. And, thanks for help me. :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, I am developing my earlier comment into an answer. This is a case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality which says that, for all real $n$-tuples $(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ it holds that $$(c_1^2+c_2^2+\cdots+c_n^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+\cdots+b_n^2)\ge(c_1 b_1 + c_2 b_2+\cdots+c_n b_n)^2.$$
Take $$(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)=(\sqrt{a_1},\sqrt{a_2},\ldots,\sqrt{a_n})$$ and $$(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_2}},\ldots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}}\right)$$ for your positive real $n$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ and you get the desired inequality. As for how to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, there is a well-known elementary method by using the discriminant of a quadratic. I'm sure that you can research it. Hope that helps.